# Append Array To UserDefaults Without Removing Original UserDefault Info

Tags: arrays, swift, save, userdefaults

So I am making an array of appended objects. My problem is that I want to add the objects without removing the original objects. Once I append the objects, I see them. But when I add new objects, the old objects are gone, and replaced by the older objects. How can I keep both through NSUserDefaults?

So far, I have done lots of research, and haven't found anything.

```
case 0:
            self.array.append("Instagram")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 1:
            self.array.append("Snapchat")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 2:
            self.array.append("VSCO")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 3:
            self.array.append("Pinterest")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 4:
            self.array.append("Tiktok")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 5:
            self.array.append("Twitter")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 6:
            self.array.append("Facebook")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 7:
            self.array.append("Google")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 8:
            self.array.append("Flickr")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 9:
            self.array.append("iFunny")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 10:
            self.array.append("Tumblr")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 11:
            self.array.append("Viber")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 12:
            self.array.append("Vine")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        case 13:
            self.array.append("WhatsApp")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
        default:
            print("Error")
            print(self.array)
```

No Error Messages

Comment: what does a `print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "addedAccounts"))` give ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you load `self.array` with the current values from UserDefaults. Then you can update the array and then update UserDefaults with the updated array.

During some appropriate initialization:

```
self.array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "addedAccounts") as? [String] ?? []
```

Then your `switch`:

```
var newVal: String?
switch whatever {
case 0: newVal = "Instagram"
case 1: newVal = "Snapchat"
// and the rest
}
if let newVal = newVal {
    self.array.append(newVal)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.array, forKey: "addedAccounts")
}
```

BTW - It would be a lot simpler to replace that `switch` with an array of accounts names.